# pass php variable to html form in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova

I am developing an app that helps the users in checking out tourist attractions within 30 miles. (All the lat,lon of places are stored in mysql) I have done this using MIT App Inventor. To get it on iOS, I am using phonegap. & github repo.

In phonegap, I can use only index.html file. where should I place the php file
I tried these two options
i) Display.php in github 
 
When I ran the app, it showed the php file as such.
ii)Display.php in remote server This time, it prompted, Complete action using Browser or Chrome (control goes outside the app)

Pl. help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a remote server with php. Your file has to handle an API call and create a json response. Then you can simply call that API from your index.html using javascript.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

It says,

> Q: CAN YOU USE PHP/ASP/JSF/JAVA/.NET WITH PHONEGAP?
>   A:  A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I used XMLHTTPRequest to fetch data and passed to js variable in index.html. Fetched data-multiple lat,long .In order to plot google map on canvas. I stored it in a string.ilocArr.forEach(function(item){
   delimiter = ',';
   start = 1;
   result = item.split(delimiter, start+1).join(delimiter);
   //alert(result);
  // latR=result.substring(result.indexOf(',')+1);
   latR=result.split(',');
  // alert(latR);
   tmpDat1 +="&markers=color:blue|label:U|" +latR[0]+","+latR[1];
  // alert(tmpDat1);
   //option.value = result;
   //list.appendChild(option);
});

Comment: I used XMLHTTPRequest to fetch data and passed to js variable in index.html. Fetched data is multiple lat,long .In order to plot multiple markers google map on canvas, I stored it in a string.     locArr.forEach(function(item){   newLoc=item.split(',');    tmpDat1 +="&markers=color:blue|label:U|" +newLoc[0]+","+newLoc[1];});                  I use this value in the url - var tile =  "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=" + lat + "," +long + "&zoom=13&size=400x200"+tmpDat1l;  When I run the app, I get this msg-  &markers=color:blue|label:U|<?php php script is displayed

Comment: Sorry abt my confusing post.  To put it simply, i store multiple markers in a string---  var tmpDat1= &markers=lat1,long1&markers=lat2,long2&markers=lat3,long3&markers=lat4,long4.   I use this in the url --  var google_tile = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," +longitude + "&zoom=13&size="+c.width+"x"+c.height+tmpDat1l+"&sensor=false&key=xxxdddddxx";      it doesn't work. pl help